# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId; React Native App

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I've been trying to run my react native application, but it crashed when  started and the debugger didn't return any error, so I checked the log cat in Android Studio and it shows me the following error: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom / google / firebase / iid / FirebaseInstanceId;**

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId"**

The React-Native version that I am using is: **0.61.5**
And the version of react-native-firebase that I have installed is **5.6.0**

It has already been a recent failure, since previously the app worked correctly and I have not made any changes to the firebase integration either

Comment: Have you updated anything recenlty? Android studio, react-native? How are you running your application? Try running it directly from Android studio, to maybe get better view of what goes wrong. Seems like there's some problem with firebase installation.

Comment: Do u use @amplify/pushnotifications? They use deprecated firebase messaging version of 12.0.1. Make sure you dont have version conflict with some other package

Answer (score 5):

To debug this, first I would suggest running `adb logcat` and seeing what Java error you are getting. If it errors out on the not being able to find the required Java classes, then try adding the following to your project:

app/build.gradle file (dependencies section):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid'
```

(You might need to provide a version for this package as well)

Answer (score 2):

I have getting same error, I fixed this error by uninstalling old version and installing new version of push notification.

```
uninstall:
npm uninstall react-native-push-notification
install:
npm i react-native-push-notification
```

since react-native-push-notification upgraded to new version v7.x so that, while installing app it give above error.

checkout this -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue, in react-native-push-notification (FirebaseInstanceId has been deprecated and now removed). Sounds like you are using a lib that is using that that here. It should be fixed later on, but for now you can add the following to your `android/build.gradel` file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.0.0"
    }
```

I had also to update these libs (you will get compile errors if you don't, so you may have others to update):

```
-    "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.8",
+    "react-native-device-info": "^8.1.3",

-    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.0",
+    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
```

This is in reference to this [issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/5293)

Comment: That worked but when doing the build it generated these errors:

bundling failed: SyntaxError: \ mobile-app \ node_modules \ react-native-device-info \ src \ index.ts: Unexpected token (770: 12)

   768 | }
   769 |
> 770 | export type {AsyncHookResult, DeviceType, LocationProviderInfo, PowerState};

But if I remove the type reserved word the error disappears, do you think I can generate an error later?

Comment: That smells like a TS version issue. Not sure which version you are using, but you should check the react-native-device-info site for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

wix/react-native-notifications
This lib having issue with refreshToken() Method.

```
Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId"
```

so just remove / reinstall the package, if still error is coming then we have to wait for next bug fix release of this lib or

we can manually change native code to make it working.

below is link of lib

https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/issues?q=FirebaseInstanceId